# How do I select N items from array with starting index higher than "array.length"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

If I have an array of `n` number of adverts which have class `'ad'`. For example; when n = 5:

```
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
```

I want to `removeClass('hide')` 3 items the array starting with an index `i`, which is a counter, but treating `$('.ad')` as an infinite loop:

if `i = 0`:

```
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
```

if `i = 1`:

```
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
```

if `i = 2`:

```
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad">...</div>
<div class="ad hide">...</div>
```

**NB** There is a "business" reason random ordering the array of adverts isn't a solution. They must be displayed in sequential order.

**How do I create a selector that selects the three items as above?**

This doesn't achieve what I want, but shows what I mean - e.g.  :

```
var adIndex = 8;

adIndex = adIndex / $('.ad').length;

$('.ad').slice(adIndex, adIndex+3).removeClass('hide');
```

Many thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: case shown for `i=0` makes sense...the others don't. Either need a better explanation of filtering rules or fix the other 2 cases in the question

Comment: You basically want to slice of 3 items from an array of n = 5, for example??

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @akinjide question is as vague as the cases shown and lack of proper explanation why they would be the way you show them. Are you sure this is what your expected results are?

Comment: You need to clarify your logic for what to do when  `i` is `0`, `1`, or `2`. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RhecilCodes What if the list of the DOM Nodes exceed 5 is the i constant?

Comment: When is`i = 0`, you're showing the first three ads, when `i = 1`, you're showing the next three, but there isn't a #6, so start again from #1. etc

Comment: @charlietfl I am trying to understand what he wants to achieve

Comment: I guess there is an error in example... first case is correct (i=0) but second should be i=3 and third i=1. Or explanation is incorrect. But as it is now, it doesn't make sense

Comment: @RhecilCodes ok...seems like what was missing was "groups of 3" where `i` defines the group not the start index

Comment: @RhecilCodes ... I think I understand, or at least reproduced your example. `i` in your case is number of 3-item-groups? not index! So `i=0` equals index of 0. `i=1` equals index of 3, `i=2` equals index of 6. Is this correct? I made func for both options below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution as it will consider your `$('.ad')` as an infinite loop exactly as you mentioned:

```js
var ads = $('.ad');
var len = ads.length;
var adIndex = 8;

if (adIndex > len) {
  adIndex = adIndex % len;
}

for (var i = adIndex; i < adIndex + 3; i++) {
  if (i >= len) {
    ads.eq(i - len).removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    ads.eq(i).removeClass('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ad hide">1</div>
<div class="ad hide">2</div>
<div class="ad hide">3</div>
<div class="ad hide">4</div>
<div class="ad hide">5</div>
```

Comment: use `eq()` instead of creating new objects that require dom search every iteration `var $ads = $('.ad'); //cache once before looping` .... then in loop  `$ads.eq(i).removeClass....`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for this perfect comment, the answer is edited to reflect that.

Comment: much cleaner and more effiicent

Comment: @charlietfl Indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
N % length
```

To rotate the index.

```
8 % 5 = 3
```

Then pick 3 items from that index, since it rotates you can create an array like this to pick the indexes it should show.

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

// for N
// var arr = Array.from({ length: $('.ad').length }, (n, i) => i);
// arr = arr.concat(arr);
```

Knowing the indexes that should be shown, filter the elements and show them.

```
$('.ad').filter(i => indexes.indexOf(i) !== -1);
```

I'm calculating the index based on "i" (`time`).

```
var time = 2;
var adIndex = (time * 3) % $('.ad').length;
```

Full example:

```js
var time = 2;
var adsToDisplay = 3;

var adIndex = (time * adsToDisplay) % $('.ad').length;
var arr = Array.from({ length: $('.ad').length }, (n, i) => i);
arr = arr.concat(arr);

var indexes = arr.slice(adIndex, adIndex + 3);

var showAds = $('.ad').filter(i => indexes.indexOf(i) !== -1);
var hideAds = $('.ad').filter(i => indexes.indexOf(i) === -1);

showAds.removeClass('hide');
hideAds.addClass('hide');
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ad hide">0</div>
<div class="ad hide">1</div>
<div class="ad hide">2</div>
<div class="ad hide">3</div>
<div class="ad hide">4</div>
```

Comment: This isn't scaleable unless you programatically create the matching array. OP says they have `n` unknown number of items

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right and I still think example is contradictory with text, resolution for core of problem (without JQuery and HTML) would be this:

```
function getPositions(i, arr) {
  for (pos = 0; pos < 3; pos++) {
    var item = (pos+i) < arr.length ? arr[pos+i] : arr[pos+i-arr.length];
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Function takes `i` and `array` as input and outputs array indexes. To apply this in HTML and JQuery only `console.log` needs to be replaced with some action on array item.

In case `i` means "i groups of 3" then small change does it:

```
function getPositions(i, arr) {
  i = i*3 % arr.length;
  for (pos = 0; pos < 3; pos++) {
    var item = (pos+i) < arr.length ? arr[pos+i] : arr[pos+i-arr.length];
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```